# button functionality in webpart

Tags: javascript

I have added a script editor and created a button using jscript. 
My requirement is when I click on button it should open cmd prompt in user machine and run ipconfig. How to achieve this. Working on o365

Comment: You can't do it with JS

Comment: any limitation with jscript? how can I achieve then?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible but it may be worth looking at node.js https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open any windows installed application like notepad, cmd etc from a browser or website, you have work with custom url protocols. Please research about it. 
We need to register that custom url protocol in the registry. And afterwards if we type in that custom url in the browser it will open up the application. In your case you redirecting your button click to that url should work.

Few examples
https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols?mobile_site=true